# Error saving role permissions in Drupal 10

Tags: civievent, drupal, permissions

On a fairly fresh installation I deactivated the Events component and get the following error when trying to save Drupal's user permissions:

> RuntimeException: Adding non-existent permissions to a role is not
> allowed. The incorrect permissions are "register for events", "view
> event info", "view event participants". in
> Drupal\user\Entity\Role->calculateDependencies() (line 207 of
> /opt/drupal/web/core/modules/user/src/Entity/Role.php).

It does not occur with active Events component and unchecking those three permissions and then disabling Events fixes it as well. Is this a (Drupal) bug?

Comment: Something similar came up a while ago but it seemed fixed: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4413

Comment: Have just hit the same after disabling CiviMail in Drupal 10.2&CiviCRM 5.68.0,